# Laravel Collection Loop to another Collection

Tags: php, laravel

How to loop the eloquent collection from one to another? I'm just getting first line of array. I have more than 4 array in the collection.

```
$queries = Students::where('year',"=", 1)->get();
$students = new Students();
foreach ($queries as $query) {
    $students->name = $query->name;
    $students->faculty = $query->faculty ."Add something";
    $students->year = $query->year;
}
dd($students);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to change the collection a bit before I print to json. For example, I want add something behind the faculty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to change the collection a bit before I print to json. For example, I want add something behind the faculty

Use the [`transform()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-transform) method to modify collection:

```
$students = Students::where('year', 1)->get();
$students->transform(function($i) {
    $i->faculty = $i->faculty . 'add something';
    return $i;
});
```

You also can use [resource classes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers) to transform the data before returning JSON response.

Comment: Tested, working really well. Voted this as answer. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map) to modify collection-

```
$queries = $queries->map(function($query){
        $query->faculty = $query->faculty."kfjhgli";
        return $query;
    });
return $queries;
```